# I can't find reason about my console output

Tags: c, fonts, console

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned int map1[20][20] = {
    
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
};

void display(){
    int i, k;
    

    for(i=0; i< 20; i++){
        for(k=0; k< 20; k++){
                
            switch(map1[i][k]){
            case 0:
                printf("□");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("  ");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("®");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("♡");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("♥");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){

    display();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to display my game map.

[image]

The right side of my game map is so weird. So, I change the font of console and I can get my right game map.

[image]

Why is it printing like this? Is it the font problem of console?

I'm using windows 11 and updated recently. Is it related?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving double spacing for case 1 which is causing the issue.

Instead of there being 18 spaces, there's 36 making the rows and columns un-even.

Use this instead

```
case 1:
    printf(" ");
    break;
```

Comment: I suspect halving the empty spaces would crash the right boxes into the middle of the map, since in the original font, it seems a box is large two spaces, so the solution could be printing a space after each character. The consequence would be having the character on the left or right side of its "box"

Comment: Personally I like to use 0x20 to indicate a space, but I'm used to assembly so I don't know if that's valid C syntax or not.